# How do I delete files that are not listed in the project from the hard drive?

Tags: xcode

I had a big project with a bunch of files I was not using. Little by little, I started removing the references to those files from xcode, until I got the project completely cleaned up.
What I want to do now is to remove all these unused files from my hard drive for good.

Is there an automated way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when you delete file from xcode it will give you options like "remove reference only" and "delete".

"remove references only" will just remove the reference in xcode but wont physically delete it from your hard-disk. you can check that practically if you go to the directory which you had mentioned while creating the project and go to the classes directory, you can still see file you had deleted still residing on the hard-disk.

"Delete" will not only remove the references from xcode but it removes the file permanently from the directory where you created your project and you can repeat the same experiment for this case too.

one more way of deleting the file permanently is by using the  Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

1- In the finder, in your app project create a sub folder.
2- Put all your project source files into it.
3- Open your project into XCode, all your files will be red (missing).

4- Then little by little, put the good files back at their original place.
5- When all is done, clean all, compile, build, ensure you don't have missing files.

6- If that works, put the sub folder that only contains non used files on an USB key and delete it from the project folder.
7- Remove the USB key.
8- Try again to clean, build, run.

9- If it still works, trash the non needed files.